# Dialogflow v2 api for edit intent

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

How to edit an intent via V2 api of dialogflow?

I have read google's Manage intents with the API on

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/manage-intents#create_intent

Is it possible to edit an intent in v2 api?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can update an Intent by using the [projects.agent.intents.patch](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents/patch) API method and providing the Intent as the body of the message.

Most libraries have a method that supports this as well.

Comment: I want to do it in php can you please share some example how t0 do it?